# allow one audio player to play at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple audio players, each with a play and stop button, on one page. The only issue I have is when you click one play button, and then another, they play on top of one another. Can someone help me with the code I would need to stop whatever song is playing when another play button is clicked. Here's are my code. Thank you

```js
function disableButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;
}

function change() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.src = "https://lms.testing.com/je_audio/html/button2.png"
}
```

```css
#btn1 {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<audio id="player">
    <source src="https://lms.testing.com/els_audio/PATAudios/Q1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser has not support the audio element.
    </audio>

<div>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play('play'); disableButton(this)"><img src="https://lms.testing.com/je_audio/html/button1.png" width="95" height="28" alt="button" id="image" onclick="change();"></button>

</div>
```

Comment: Grab all audio elements, iterate over them, call stop(): `document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(el => el.stop())` (and don't use inline code, write a click handler function and assign it)

Answer (score 3):

Listen for the `play` event on all the `<audio>` elements.
Whenever one audio element starts playing, pause all the other ones.

```
// Get all <audio> elements.
const audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

// Pause all <audio> elements except for the one that started playing.
function pauseOtherAudios({ target }) {
  for (const audio of audios) {
    if (audio !== target) {
      audio.pause();
    }
  }
}

// Listen for the 'play' event on all the <audio> elements.
for (const audio of audios) {
  audio.addEventListener('play', pauseOtherAudios);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is for all the elements first to stop the audio that was previously running audio and then change their images back to play, and try to play the audio for the current media button you are using. Using Class to detect all the Elements using

document.querySelectorAll('.playerButton')

this will help you find all the player button and similarly give a class like AudioFile to that audio that you are using and use the stop() function to stop the audio and then start the audio for the current button clicked using this function.
I hope this will help you, in executing the functionality you are trying to achieve. 
you can use the below-given function as an example on how to stop the audio

```
 function stopAudio(audio) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
 } 

 stopAudio(audio)
```